# How to remove loaded script and add new script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a demo in which I have added a query string in the URL. When I load my HTML I get the value of my query. I want it so that if the query string has the value "simple", it removes the JS file that is loaded.

If it finds a value other than "simple" it should load another JS file.

I Google searched it for solution, but nothing works.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/copynode.js" type="text/javascript" id="dynamic_files"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function(){
        // full load
        var query = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1));
        console.log("---------------------");
        var index=query.indexOf("=")
        query=query.substr(index+1,query.length);
        console.log(query);
        if(query=="simple"){
       alert('if--');
            //$('#dynamic_files').remove();
        }else{
            alert('else--');
            $('#dynamic_files').remove();
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = 'js/index.js';
            document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].appendChild(script);
        }

    });

</script>
</head>

<body >
    <h1>My Web Page</h1>
    <p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadScript()">Load Script</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the purpose of removing the js file?

Comment: purpose is if it simple (in query string)I want to use that file .other I want to use other file

Comment: can you further explain those "that" files?. its confusing

Comment: if it simple in query string .I want to use copynode.js file.else I want to remove copynode.js file and add index.js file

Comment: The file itself is irrelevant, instead check if a specific function exists.

Comment: please check update of my Question

Comment: Have you seen jQuery's [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)?

Comment: No sir nevwr use that ...

Comment: I want if there is "file:///D:/svn-stacker/WebContent/a.html?mode=simpl"..it remove copynode.js and add index.js file in dom

Comment: do you know how to use php?

Comment: It's a link you can click and you *are* using jQuery.  Removing a file is unlikely to help... it's either run once or has methods/listeners/etc. which are run periodically.  Removing a function which is a listener won't automatically detach it.  I'd go back to the drawing board on design of your concept for a solid long-term solution.

Comment: but "file:///D:/svn-stacker/WebContent/a.html?mode=simple" it don't do anything

Comment: @natewiley I am mobile application developer not PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the value of the `String` first then write a function like :

```
function checkString(){
 if($('#ID_OF_ELEMENT_OF_THE_STRING').value == "simple"){
    //load the script needed
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', 'http://mysite/my.js');
    head.appendChild(script);
 }else{
    //load the other part.
 }

}
```

Comment: how to remove js file.This function is ale to add .but how to remove the loaded file

Comment: secondly why I got downvoted..I am facing a problem .is it not a good Question ?>

Comment: in example you'll only load a file right after the string was checked, that way you dont need to delete any

Comment: hmmm ..I thhink you are right..can you please upvote the Question thanks for anwering